# Dynamic (Changing) JSON to Hive Schema using UDF

Tags: python, hive-udf

I am having a JSON file with below structure:

```
{
    "A": {
        "AId": {
            "AId": "123",
            "idType": "XYZ"
        },
        "fN": "RfN",
        "oN": "ON",
        "mail": [
            "abc@kml.com",
            "xyz@kml.com"
        ],
        "ph": [
            {
                "nu": "999-999-9999",
                "t": "Of",
                "ext": "1234"
            },
            {
                "nu": "999-999-9999",
                "t": "Of",
                "ext": "1234"
            }
        ],
        "add": {
            "addLines": [
                "Addr Line 1",
                "Addr Line 2"
            ],
            "c": "C",
            "sC": "S"
        },
        "c": [
            {
                "cT": "CT",
                "cN": "9999"
            }
        ],
        "serId": "XXX"
    },
    "int": {
        "endTS": null,
        "cId": {
            "cId": "null",
            "cC": "null"
        },
        "cmpgn": null,
        "sTC": null,
        "cCID": {
            "tIC": "null",
            "tC": "null",
            "cC": []
        },
        "int": "Un",
        "rep": [],
        "pp": "null",
        "cf": {
            "a": 1234,
            "b": 1234
        },
        "iA": {
            "sId": {
                "s": "null",
                "sId": "null"
            },
            "cId": "null",
            "lId": "null"
        },
        "sRequest": null,
        "vBu": "VBU",
        "fId": "FId",
        "k": [
            "k"
        ],
        "eng": [
            {
                "EC": "E_CODE::12345",
                "cT": "2011-01-28T23:12:12.666Z",
                "up": null,
                "rep": {
                    "rep": {
                        "type": "B",
                        "id": "ID"
                    },
                    "fullName": "FullName"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Few Points:

1. From the above structure need to create hive schema.
2. JSON structure can change dynamically. For each change in JSON structure. Need to regenerate hive schema.
3. I tried, using JSON library of Python; but not of much use. I was not able to obtain tag names, which can be used as field names of hive schema.
4. Want to auto mate the process of generating JSON to Hive schema.
5. Exploring Python JSON Encoder, Decoder class; to parse the JSON and put own logic to create Hive schema out of it. But there is no good example available to use JSON Encoder, Decoder class.
6. Finally, want to put everything in form of Python UDF. I good with any Java UDF alternative too.

Note: The above JSON can be structured using http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Note: The above JSON can be structured using http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Atleast, if someone can help on how to parse the JSON; to obtain the Hive Schema structure through code. Will be of great help.